# How can I change the value of input to upper-case with my customTextbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to change the value of input with my custom `Textbox`. I try to add class text-uppercase but the value is still lower-case by default.

**My HtmlHelper class is**:

```
public static class CustomTextBoxHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Custom_TextBox<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var dict = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        return helper.Custom_TextBox(expression, dict);
    }
    public static MvcHtmlString Custom_TextBox<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        return helper.Custom_TextBox(expression, htmlAttributes);
    }


    public static MvcHtmlString Custom_TextBox<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {

        ModelMetadata oModelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

        if (htmlAttributes == null)
        {
            htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        htmlAttributes.Add("type", "text");
        htmlAttributes.Add("name", oModelMetadata.DisplayName);
        htmlAttributes.Add("id", oModelMetadata.DisplayName);


        if (htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("class"))
        {
            htmlAttributes["class"] += " text-uppercase";
        }
        else
        {
            htmlAttributes.Add("class", "text-uppercase");
        }
        if (htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("value"))
        {
            htmlAttributes["value"] = htmlAttributes["value"].ToString().ToUpper();
        }
        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

But `text-uppercase` didn't solve my problem.I know that is `CSS` property.
I also tried to add onchange event.But I need to add my script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    $("#myTextbox").val($("#myTextbox").val().toUpperCase());
}
</script>
```

How can I add this script to my **helperclass**? Or any other ideas?

Comment: try adding htmlAttributes with style as  htmlAttributes.Add("transform", "uppercase  ")

Comment: @AnupamSingh thank you for answer but it's not working .When i enter the text with lower-case still the value is lower-case.

Comment: Try to inspect html generated by the same

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem but there may be  more effective solutions. 
I added the script as string at the bottom of my Custom_Textbox function instead of using htmlattribute "value" ,like that:

```
   if (htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("onchange"))
        {
            htmlAttributes["onchange"] = "myFunctionThatMustNotMergeAnyOtherFunctionName()";
        }
        else htmlAttributes.Add("onchange", "myFunctionThatMustNotMergeAnyOtherFunctionName()");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(helper.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToString() + @"<script>
function myFunctionThatMustNotMergeAnyOtherFunctionName() {
    $('#"+oModelMetadata.DisplayName+"').val($('#"+oModelMetadata.DisplayName+@"').val().toUpperCase());
}
</script>");
```

Now, my value is always upper-case.
Thank you for your interest.